# Segmentation fault from boost (boost:filesystem:exists)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I recently upgradeted my boost library to 1.63 version. But a function, boost:filesystem:exists now doesn't work . Before with boost library 1.54 the code was ok. Instead now goes in segmentation fault. :

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs=boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fs::path selfpath=fs::system_complete("Testa2.cpp");
    cout<<selfpath<<endl;

    if(fs::exists(selfpath.c_str()))
    cout<<"Never here"<<endl;
```

and it compiles with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 Testa5.cpp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

but exists goes in segmentation fault.

How is it possible?
How can I fix it?

(I'm on Ubuntu)
(I installated boost from here:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/boost.html)

Comment: Should your statement:  fs::path selfpath=fs::system_complete("Testa:   Actually be written as:  fs::path selfpath=fs::system_complete("Testa:");   ???   There should be almost no problems with Boost.   And you claim that this exact same instruction works with g++ on the same computer?

Comment: @Dr t You have rason, I'm wrong. Now I modify the question

Comment: It works here online: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/606b19bec055ba5b (using program_options for parsing command line)

Answer (score 3):

You installed binaries not built for the (Ubuntu) distribution you are using.

Prefer to use the distro-specific packages or compile from source, using the same compiler version and flags as you use when compiling your program.

Anything else runs into ABI issues, which is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

So, on Ubuntu, usually install boost like

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem was another. The new boost library was installed in /usr/lib and the old is remained in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and the .so symbolic link did still reference to old version. I changed the link doing point to right library and I resolved.  However thanks

Comment: That's basically the same problem right: you run against a different version than compiled in -> ABI difference. Having to manually fix symlinks is proof that you subverted your distribution's package management. The symlinks should be automatic

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're linking against the correct version of boost, as Umbert mentioned in a previous answer's comment.

For example:
My linker was looking in directory:
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` for `libboost_filesystem.so` (version 1.58).
While the correct path should for me is:
`/usr/local/lib/` where `libboost_filesystem.so` (version 1.67) resides.